# How to convert midi to wav using Timidity++?

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am actually trying to use timidity lib in my android project using the jni interface.
The problem is I need to create the shared lib for that including some C files.

I don't know the C files/classes and methods in them that are used for the above task.
So Please help me ,if any of you C developer have the idea or has the experience of using this library.